# Same gender probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

"We're thinking about children - with the assumption that babies are boys with probability 0.51, girls with probability 0.49, and births are independent.

You're a researcher interested in large families: as part of your latest project, you've decided to interview 50 families in which there are exactly eight children.

What's the probability that, in at least one of the 50 families, the children will all be of the same gender?"

I can't figure this one out.. If someone could at least help me with the correct formula, that would be awesome.

Comment: Hint: figure it out for a single family. Then use the fact that births in different families are independent and therefore the problem can be modeled as a binomial distribution.

Comment: -1: New username + sneering allusion to homosexuality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that in any one family all of the eight children are of the same gender is
$$p=0.51^8+0.49^8$$
The probability that, in at least one of the 50 families, the children will all be of the same gender is then
$$q=1-(1-p)^{50}$$
(by complementarity.)

Comment: Gah. Thanks. Knowing where to correctly put the parenthesis helps... haha

Comment: @Otherwise Isn't it possible to do it directly, without complementarity? If we know `p` as the probability of having a family with all children of the same gender, can we directly calculate the probability of having more than one family with at all children of the same gender by multiplying p*50, since we want at least one of the families of that kind? If not, what would p*50 be?

Comment: Can you please explain why q has to be like that? At first I tried p * 50 but it is incorrect. Why is it?

Comment: DatVM: What you are calculating is "at least one family" or the complement probability of no families. So you take the complement probability of having all babies of the same gender raise it to the power 50 (not just multiply, because it's a probability -- Eg. if you have 51% of something and do it twice you aren't guaranteed to have it happen).

Answer (score 0):

For one family, what is the probability that all babies are boys? What about all babies are girls? The probability that *not* all babies are of the same gender is $1$ minus these two numbers. Call it $p$.

The probability that in all 50 families not all babies are of the same gender is then $p^{50}$.

The probability that in at least one of the 50 families all babies are of the same gender is then $1-p^{50}$.

Can you figure out $p$?